# Query SQL not working in ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a little problem with my code, I want to execution query using ajax, but the query does not run. Is there an error in my code?
Here's Query SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE date = '2015-05-28' ORDER BY start_time ASC
```

Here's my code :

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-load">Click</button>
<div class="show"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-load").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "show.php",
                data: "date='2015-05-28'",
                success: function(data){
                    $(".show").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

Show.php :

```
require 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$date = $_POST['date'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE date = '".$date."' ORDER BY start_time ASC";
     foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo "<p class='list-event'>$row[name]</p>";
            echo "<p class='list-event'>$row[date]</p>";
     }
Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: remove your quotes in `data: "date=2015-05-28",`

Comment: I don't see any elements of class btn-next in your code.

Comment: in your script ajax passing data 'date' failed use this `date:'2015-05-28',` instead of "date='2015-05-28'",

Comment: @Sathish `data` can be sent as `string` - `data: "date=2015-05-28"` or `object` - `data: {date:'2015-05-28'}` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: off course @sean he get the input from date `$_POST['date'];` so I told like that

Comment: try  data: "date=2015-05-28"   ...

Comment: You are also open to injections with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var post_data = {};
post_data['date'] = '2015-05-28';

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "show.php",
    data: post_data,
    success: function(data){
        $(".show").html(data);
    }
});
```

Also, i recommend using prepared statement on your query, since youre already using PDO. Make the most out of it

Comment: `data` can be sent as `string` - `data: "date=2015-05-28"` or `object` - `data: {date:'2015-05-28'}` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. issue is the quotes in the string. Your answer is correct, but not the only method.

Comment: yes but I think in the server side, the ajax data must be an object, if you're retrieving it using $_POST['date']

Comment: nope, it can be a string as from the docs, `It is converted to a query string, if not already a string`. So even though your `object` is easier to read, it will be converted in to a string anyway. php will read the `date=...&otherdata=...` in `$_POST`.

Comment: if i use tha i got an msg error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

You should pass data like this

`data: {date : '2015-05-28'},`

Comment: `data` can be sent as `string` - `data: "date=2015-05-28"` or `object` - `data: {date:'2015-05-28'}` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. issue is the quotes in the string. Your answer is correct, but not the only method.

Comment: Edit your question with the modifications you did to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

change   data: "date='2015-05-28'" to   data: { date: '2015-05-28'},

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-next").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "show.php",
                data: { date: '2015-05-28'},
                success: function(data){
                    $(".show").html(data);
                }

            });
        });
     });
```

query:`$sql = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE date = '$date' ORDER BY start_time ASC";`

Comment: if i use tha i got an msg error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier